# Условия внутри цикла while

Tags: python, циклы, while, python-3.8

> Как исправить код так, чтобы после неправильного пароля можно было вводить пароль ещё 2 раза (всего 3 попыток).
> Зацикливаться должен только **пароль** (переменная **password**)!

```
name = input ("Введите ваше имя:\n")
if name == "Иван":
    print ('Здравствуйте,' + name + '!')
    jkl = 0
    while jkl < 3:
    password = input ('Введите ваш пароль:\n')
    if password == 'wasd666':
        print ('Правильный пароль!')
        surname = input ("Введите вашу фамилию:\n")
        if surname == 'Иванов':
            print ('Правильная фамилия!')
            nickname = input ('Введите ваш никнейм:\n')
            if nickname == 'ivansky':
                print ('Правильный никнейм!')
                denr = input("""Введите дату вашего дня рождения в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ.:\n""")
                if denr == '13.06.2002.' or '13.06.2002':
                    print ('Правильная дата дня рождения!')
                    password_file = input ("Введите пароль от файла:\n")
                    if password_file == 'qwerty99':
                        print ('Правильный пароль от файла!')
                        #конец
                    else:
                        print ("Неправильный пароль от файла!")
                else:
                    print ('Неправильная дата дня рождения!')                                 
            else:
                print ("Неправильный никнейм!")
        else:
            print ('Неправильная фамилия!')
    else:
        print ("Неправильный пароль!")
        jkl += 1
        if jkl == 1:
            print ("У вас осталось попытки")
        if jkl == 2:
            print ("У вас осталось 1 попытка")
        if jkl == 3:
            print ("У вас последняя попытка!")
else:
    print ('Неправильное имя!')
input("Press Enter")
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот уже изменённый код (добавил цикл `for`, `break`, а также изменил условия `if`, но оставил код Вашего типа):

```
name = input ("Введите ваше имя:\n")
if name == "Иван":
    print ('Здравствуйте,' + name + '!')
    for i in range(3):
        password = input ('Введите ваш пароль:\n')
        if password == 'wasd666':
            print ('Правильный пароль!')
            surname = input ("Введите вашу фамилию:\n")
            if surname == 'Иванов':
                print ('Правильная фамилия!')
                nickname = input ('Введите ваш никнейм:\n')
                if nickname == 'ivansky':
                    print ('Правильный никнейм!')
                    denr = input("""Введите дату вашего дня рождения в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ.:\n""")
                    if denr == '13.06.2002.' or '13.06.2002':
                        print ('Правильная дата дня рождения!')
                        password_file = input ("Введите пароль от файла:\n")
                        if password_file == 'qwerty99':
                            print ('Правильный пароль от файла!')
                            #конец
                            break #выход из цикла
                        else:
                            print ("Неправильный пароль от файла!")
                    else:
                        print ('Неправильная дата дня рождения!')                                 
                else:
                    print ("Неправильный никнейм!")
            else:
                print ('Неправильная фамилия!')
        else:
            print ("Неправильный пароль!")
            if i == 0: print ("У вас осталось 2 попытки")
            if i == 1: print ("У вас последняя попытка!")
else:
    print ('Неправильное имя!')
input("Press Enter")
```

Comment: @Иван _помогло?_

Answer (score 0):

Я бы не делал такую ступенчатую структуру, а пошел бы от обратного - завернул бы всё в функцию и при неправильных ответах просто сразу из нее выходил бы (можно с некоторым значением, показывающим, что произошла ошибка, например `return -1`)

```
def get_data():
    name = input ("Введите ваше имя:\n")
    if name != "Иван":
        print ('Неправильное имя!')
        return

    print (f'Здравствуйте, {name}!')

    jkl = 0
    while jkl < 3:
        password = input ('Введите ваш пароль:\n')
        if password != 'wasd666':
            print("Неправильный пароль!")
            jkl += 1
            if jkl == 1:
                print("У вас осталось 2 попытки")
            if jkl == 2:
                print("У вас осталось 1 попытка")
            if jkl == 3:
                print("У вас последняя попытка!")
    if jkl >= 3:
        return -1
            
    surname = input ("Введите вашу фамилию:\n")
    if surname != 'Иванов':
        print('Неправильная фамилия!')
        return
        
    print ('Правильная фамилия!')

    nickname = input ('Введите ваш никнейм:\n')

    if nickname != 'ivansky':
        print ("Неправильный никнейм!")
        return

    print ('Правильный никнейм!')
    denr = input('Введите дату вашего дня рождения в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ.:\n')

   if denr not in ['13.06.2002.', '13.06.2002']:
       print ('Неправильная дата дня рождения!')                                 
       return

   print ('Правильная дата дня рождения!')

   password_file = input ("Введите пароль от файла:\n")

   if password_file != 'qwerty99':
       print ("Неправильный пароль от файла!")
       return

   print ('Правильный пароль от файла!')
```

или завернул бы точно такой же код в исключение

```
try:
    ....
except:
```

и вместо `return` бросал бы исключения

В общем в любом случае избавился бы от ВЛОЖЕННОСТИ, которая есть у вас - она очень неудобна

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать сделать примерно так, хотя тут, конечно, есть еще над чем поработать:

```
d = [['Иван', "Введите ваше имя:\n", 'Здравствуйте, Иван!', 'Неправильное имя!'],
     ['wasd666', 'Введите ваш пароль:\n', 'Правильный пароль!', "Неправильный пароль!"],
     ['Иванов', "Введите вашу фамилию:\n", 'Правильная фамилия!', 'Неправильная фамилия!'],
     ['ivansky', 'Введите ваш никнейм:\n', 'Правильный никнейм!', "Неправильный никнейм!"],
     ['13.06.2002.', "Введите дату вашего дня рождения в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ.:\n", 'Правильная дата дня рождения!', 'Неправильная дата дня рождения!'],
     ['qwerty99', "Введите пароль от файла:\n", 'Правильный пароль от файла!', "Неправильный пароль от файла!"]]
flag = 0

for i in d:
    if input(i[1])==i[0]: print(i[2])
    else: 
        print(i[3])
        if i[0]=='wasd666':
            for j in range(2):
                print('Осталось попыток: ', 2-j)
                if input(i[1])==i[0]: 
                    print(i[2])
                    break
                else: print(i[3])
            else: flag=1
            if flag: break
        else: break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Сделаем, чтобы имя и пароль спрашивали по 3 раза, а после разъединялся.

break_flag = False  # Использование флага - для дальнейшего выхода из двойного цикла.
vvod_name = 0
vvod_passw = 0

#while True:
while vvod_name < 3:
    name = input("Введите имя: ")
    if name != "Sasha":
        print("Неверное имя пользователя!")
        vvod_name += 1
        if vvod_name == 1:
            print("У вас осталось две попытки!")
            continue
        if vvod_name == 2:
            print("У вас осталась одна попытка!")
            continue
        else:
            print("Такого пользователя не существует!")
            break
    elif name == ("Sasha"):
        print("Correct name!")
    #while True:  # Может я криво сделал, но как то у меня двойной while получился..
    while vvod_passw < 3:
        passw = input("Привет, Саша! Введи пароль (рыба-меч на en): ")
        if passw != "swordfish":
            print("Неверный пароль!")
            vvod_passw += 1
            if vvod_passw == 1:
                print("Не угадали! У вас осталось две попытки!")
                continue
            if vvod_passw == 2:
                print("Не угадали! У вас осталась одна попытка!")
                continue
            else:
                print("Password incorrect!")
                break
        else:
            break_flag = True  
            # Если условие истинно, мы устанавливаем флаг в True и прерываем внутренний цикл с помощью break.
            print("Correct password!")
            break
    if break_flag:  
     # Затем во внешнем цикле проверяем значение флага, и если оно True, прерываем и внешний цикл.
        print("breaking_flag")
        break

print("Я только учусь.. :)")
```